# Can't run android app on Nexus 7

Tags: android, deployment, sencha-touch

I'm trying to run my android app from ADT on a Nexus 7 I have connected.  It's a sencha touch hybrid app, which builds without a problem and is deployed to the device, but I then get the error:

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME(content:://jsHybugger.org/file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Can anyone shed some light on this error?

Comment: Did you mean to have 2 colons in the URL? `content:://jsHybugger`

Comment: No, sorry, that's a typo.

Should read..

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME(content://jsHybugger.org/file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by updating the jshybugger library in my project to 4.5.6 and amending the following line in my code:

```
  //super.loadUrl("content://jsHybugger.org/" + Config.getStartUrl(), 60000);
  super.loadUrl(DebugServiceClient.getDebugUrl(Config.getStartUrl()), 60000);
```

I imagine that latter change was more significant than the jshybugger update.